# Posting to a URL with PHP and no form

Tags: php, post

I'd like to use PHP to post to a URL the way a form would. Basically the same function that this form would do

```
    <form method="POST" id="foo" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="shopId" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="encodedMessage" value="<?php echo $encodedMessage; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo $signature; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="buy">
    </form></div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean How to make a server-side post? if yes look curl functions: http://it.php.net/curl

Comment: Use curl for that http://us3.php.net/curl

Comment: You should read about CURL documentation

Comment: Are you able to provide me with an example code that will work?

Answer (score 3):

you want to use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions to send an http POST request.  For example:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name1=val&name2=val2...");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this, but the easiest is probably with file_get_contents() and stream_context_create(). See this [file_get_contents() comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#102575) for an example.